# How to get values for all children nodes in a JSON class C#

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, recursion

I am currently getting values by using 3 nested forloops. I do already have JSON deserialized into someCollection class. i saw similar examples online but i was hoping someone could explain how i could make it work. 
Thank you

```
private List<Guid> GetIds(SomeCollection someList)
    {
        var list = new List<Guid>();

        for (int i = 0; i < someList.Categories.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < someList.Categories[i].Categories.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < someList.Categories[i].Categories[j].Categories.Count; k++)
                {
                    list.Add(Guid.Parse((someList.Categories[i].Categories[j].Categories[k].Key)));
                }
                list.Add(Guid.Parse((someList.Categories[i].Categories[j].Key)));
            }
            list.Add(Guid.Parse((someList.Categories[i].Key)));
        }
        return list;
```

Comment: This is a typical case where you should use recursive calls.

Comment: Thank you @Graffito. Trouble i'm having is how to implement recursion in a way that will dynamically call subcategories. i.e this code only goes down three levels. i'm not sure how to implement a condition to check if there are more subcategories available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your code in a recursive way would be:

```
var list = new List<Guid>();
GetIds(someList,list) ;

private void GetIds(SomeCollection someList,List<Guid> list)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < someList.Categories.Count; i++) 
  {
     GetIds (someList.Categories[i],list) ;
     list.Add(Guid.Parse((someList.Categories[i].Key))) ;
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Graffito very much. It worked with some minor modification and i was able to understand and learn.